# How to access ParseServer config parameters from cloud code?

Tags: parse-platform

I'm running and hosting my parse-server.  In my cloud code, I need to access some config parameters sent to ParseServer constructor.  What should I do to access them from the cloud code?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into the parse-server source code, there is no api to obtain a reference to the ParseServer object.  The easy approach is just to use env variable and process.env.